Good Postman request don’t work on my php website
On Postman, I created a query which returns me a result but the generated code (PHP-CURL) which seems correct to me does not return “false”:
Method POST
Postman Config:
Params => nothing
Authorization => default (inherit auth …)
Headers => content-type: application/json, data-type: jsonp
Body => {
“Username”: “user-name”,
“Password”: “pass-word”
}

Postman return:
{
    "access_token": "xxxxxxx",
    "token_type": "xxx",
    "expires_in": 10799,
    "userName": "user-name",
    "issued": "2024-04-26T08:58:24Z",
    "expires": "2024-04-26T11:58:24Z",
    "error": "",
    "error_description": ""
}

Postman code generate:
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://XXX/api',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
    "Username": "user-name",
    "Password": "pass-word"
}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'dataType: jsonp'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;

But $response = false
For information, I work on a local server

Is it intentional that you use data-type in the Postman, headers and dataType in CURL? Does it make any difference if you change your CURL call to use the same header name as you use in Postman?

With or without the data-type, the result remains the same on Postman or on my site.
I wonder if working on a local website could be a problem.
